# update android studio 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 not support databinding properly

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1

I made an update to android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0. After updating the gradle to latest version I get error for binding, when i change Id in XML file and then try to get that id using data Binding in Java File, it's not support after build, and after Restart I get that Id, I am bored that i want restart android studio again for data binding, and in my whole project i used binding, so when i remove it, there is many changes,

I tried this, from android developer

Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0 Canary 6 ships with an optional new compiler. To start using it, update your gradle.properties file to include the following line:

android.databinding.enableV2 = true

but, it's can't help me, is there any solution?

Comment: Same here, but I can generate Binding class after build instead of restart Android Studio.